# Expectation number of swaps in min find algorithm

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Source: TIFR 2014

Consider the problem of computing the minimum of a set of $n$ distinct numbers. We choose a permutation uniformly at random (i.e., each of the $n!$ permutations of $\langle 1,....,n\rangle$ is chosen with probability $(1/n!)$ and we inspect the numbers in the order given by this permutation. We maintain a variable MIN that holds the minimum value seen so far. MIN is initialized to $\infty$ and if we see a value smaller than MIN during our inspection, then MIN is updated. For example, in the inspection given by the following sequence, MIN is updated four times.

$$5\ 9\ 4\ 2\ 6\ 8\ 0\ 3\ 1\ 7$$

What is the expected number of times MIN is updated?

My Approach: 
We can use conditional expectation here to arrive.Let the expectation of finding the minimum of $n$ numbers be $E(X_n)$. $X_n$ is a random variable that can take values from $1$ to $n$ denoting number of swaps

Lets look at the last position.That is right most.

Probability that this is a min element is $1/n$. So 
$$E(X_n\mid \text{Last element is min})= E(X_{n-1})+1$$ because we need to do one more additional swap after finding minimum element from $1$ to $n-1$

Probability that this is not a min element is $(n-1)/n$. So 
$$E(X_n\mid \text{Last element not a min})= E(X_{n-1})$$

Conbining both we get

$$E(X_n) = \frac 1n(E(X_{n-1}) +1) + \frac {n-1}nE(X_{n-1})\\E(X_n) = \frac 1n + E(X_{n-1})\\E(X_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i$$
Recursively expand to get answer 
Please check if my idea is correct.Also improvements to the notations will be helpful

Comment: Your posts will look better and be easier to read if you format them with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: In addition to cleaning up the formatting, I corrected your final formula, which had been $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/n$.

Comment: There is one assumption you've accidently made, but didn't notice. Consider what your fomula says about the case when $n=1$.

Comment: E(X1)=1?I forgot to mention? @PaulSinclair

Comment: @Paul Sinclair what is that assumption?

Comment: $E(X_1) = 1$ is what *your formula tells you*. Now ask yourself - and this time *think about it* "does that make sense?"

Comment: Thanks you are correct. It doesnt  make sense .Ideally we start with min always initialised to first element.But in the question they have arbitarily initialised it to a very large value.So in that sense E(X1) can be 1 because of swap from large number to the first number is how understood. Thanks @Paul Sinclair for helping and even for editing.Im new to mathjax format.

Comment: Actually, never mind. I lost track of what you were doing, and started thinking of sorting the list. So if there is only one value, you would have nothing to swap. But that is a different problem (and would have a different recursion formula). For your problem $E(X_1) = 1$, since MIN starts at $\infty$. Your formula is correct. I was the one who made an accidental assumption.